# Web API for HP products

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Currently I am using HP Web JetAdmin to manage a fleet of HP products.  The interface is great but I am wanting to create some custom applications with custom interfaces.  Does anyone know of any way to get info into custom web applications or such from HP products?  I am kind of looking for a free solution here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HP Open Extensibility Platform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Open_Extensibility_Platform_%28OXP%29) provides some of the JetAdmin functionality, and may be worth looking into. They also provide an SDK. You can read more about OXP at the following

http://h20195.www2.hp.com/v2/GetPDF.aspx/4AA0-4557ENW.pdf

http://h71028.www7.hp.com/enterprise/downloads/HP_OXP-Management_FINAL.pdf

Comment: Please explain the down vote. It will help me correct the problem.

Comment: Everything you've linked to is 100% marketing. There is no code or useful information within those documents.